# How restrictive is $[\mathcal H,\mathcal V] =0$, or weaker, $[X,A_XY] = 0$?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, submersions

Let $\pi :P \to M$ be a Riemannian submersion. Let us denote by $\mathcal H$ the horizontal space of $\pi$ and by $\mathcal V$ its vertical space. I want to know restrictions and consequences of the fact (probably well know, so I am sorry if it is trivial)
$$[\mathcal H,{\mathcal V}] = 0,$$
where $[,]$ is the Lie Bracket.

Or weaker, I am also interested on the case:
$$[X,A_XY]^{\mathcal V} = 0, ~\forall X,Y \in \mathcal H,$$
where,
$$A_XY := \frac{1}{2}[X,Y]^{\mathcal V}.$$

**EDIT**

There are some remarks I have noticed. In what follows I will assume $\pi$ is a principal $G$-bundle.

If $X$ is projectable and $U^*$ is an action vector, then
$$[X,U^*] = 0.$$

The remained question for my purposes is: given $X,Y$, does there exist $V \in \mathcal V$ such that $A_XY = \frac{d}{dt}|_{t=0}\exp(tV)\cdot p, p~\in P$ where $\cdot$ denotes the $G$-action of $G$? I think the answer is yes since we have an isomorphism between $T_pG\cdot p$ and $\cal V_p$.